# PHP: JSON/AJAX live update to display data

Tags: php, json, ajax

[image]

Hi everyone,
When I delete first record, my table will live update but the order number remained '2',
 
is it possible to make it change to '1' without refresh page,
currently I am using ajax to do it, and found json_encode & json_decode maybe able to solve my problem?

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"delete_item.php",
    data:{id:del_id},
    success:
            function(){
            }
});

$(this).parents(".record").animate('fast').animate({opacity:'hide'},'slow');
```

This is for display my data

```
<tbody id='item_list'>
    <?php eitem_listItem($page, $record,$search); ?>
</tbody>
```

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of addressing this is to hide the actual id of the data row (presumably you are using id as the unique identifier for your query) - so have it as a data attribute or an id for the delete button (to give you the del_id) or other method of keeping it in the data but not displayed.

Then when you are iterating through your data to display it - have a javascript count set up so that on the display of the data - each `<tr>`  row gets its displayed index from this count - rather than the id of the actual data.

This means that you will display a 1 for the first displayed row - but the actual id that you use for the delete button may be 2 for example.

So the number on the side of the table becomes a displayed index that will always match the actual sequence of the data rows, but not necessarily will match the id of the row.